# What types of asp.net web controls could I set a background image to?

Tags: asp.net, background-image

I need to set a background image to code which is already an asp:Image control. Is there a control I could use in it's place in order for the background image to work?

The code in the master file looks like this:

```
<div style="width:21px;" class="icon-img"><asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/icon.png" Height="11"  Visible="false"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your master page.aspx

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" style="width:21px;" class="icon-img"></div>
```

Your code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    myDiv.Style("background-image") = "url('mybackground.png')"
End Sub
```

Make sure your aspx page has given an id to the div and the attribute runat="server" (which is needed to access it from the code behind).

OR:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" style="width:21px;" class="icon-img"><asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/icon.png" Height="11"  Visible="false"/></div>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    img.ImageUrl = "mybackground.png"
End Sub
```

The difference between both is that the first one uses a background-image inside your div, while the second places a real image inside the div.